# Accessing a website from javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json, xmlhttprequest

On the one side I have a local website shown in Chrome (let's call it A).
On the other side I have a PHP site, that returns some JSON data (let's call it B).

Now I would like to load the JSON data from B, and display them on A.
To so I tried to use a XMLHttpRequest, but it got me the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http:.... No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

I also tried adding " header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');" to my PHP site (B), but that did not change anything.

Comment: is your header() declaration the very first thing output back to the browser? Example of your code would be helpful.

Comment: No, it was not the first thing. After fixing that, it worked :-)